# Trying to update res.locals after database update

Tags: node.js, express

When updating a user (via database update) in my Node.JS Express app, I update a user session which then updates a res.locals.session

However, when I try to access the res.locals.session within the Jade template, the values are displayed as they were prior to the database update.

Please can you help me to find out why the res.locals.session is not updating in the template?

Here is my code (cut down for brevity):

**index.js**

```
// Store session to locals so I can use it in Jade
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});
```

**routes/user.js**

```
var User = require('../models/Users');

function displaySettings(req, res) {
    res.render('settings');
}

function saveSettings(User, req, res) {

    // Updating user

    User.update(
        { Member_id: req.session.user.Member_id }
        , { settings: req.body }
        , { upsert: false, multi: false }
        , function (err) {
            //if(err) return next(err);
            //res.json({ message : 'Success!'});
            console.log("saved");
        });

    // Retrieving user again, so that I can resave the updated user's details
    // in the res.locals.session 

    var user = User.findById(req.session.user._id, function (err, user) {
        console.log("found");
        console.log(user);
        req.session.user = user;
        console.log(req.session.user);
        res.locals.session = req.session;
        console.log(res.locals.session);
    });

    // Finally display the view

    displaySettings(req, res);
}
```

**views/settings.jade**

```
extends layout

block content

    include includes/navigation

    div.container.main

        h1.text-center User Settings

        div.row
            div.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3

                form#form-login.form-horizontal(action='/settings',method='post')
                    div#container(data-role='fieldcontain')
                        fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
                            div.form-group
                                label.col-sm-4.control-label(for='username') Paypal Email
                                div.col-sm-8

                                // The session.user.settings.paypalEmail is showing 
                                // the old value even after the user has re-saved 
                                // their settings. I'm expecting the new, updated 
                                // value to be displayed instead

                                    input.form-control(id='username',type='text',value='#{session.user.settings.paypalEmail}',name='paypalEmail')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `res.redirect('settings')` instead of calling `displaySettings(req, res)`. I think this will allow `res.locals` to update.

Answer (score 0):

what about rewriting the `saveSettings` as follows.

```
function saveSettings(User, req, res) {

    // Updating user

    User.update(
        { Member_id: req.session.user.Member_id }
        , { settings: req.body }
        , { upsert: false, multi: false }
        , function (err) {
            //if(err) return next(err);
            //res.json({ message : 'Success!'});
            console.log("saved");

     // Retrieving user again, so that I can resave the updated user's details
    // in the res.locals.session 

    var user = User.findById(req.session.user._id, function (err, user) {
        console.log("found");
        console.log(user);
        req.session.user = user;
        console.log(req.session.user);
        res.locals.session = req.session;
        console.log(res.locals.session);
        // Finally display the view

        displaySettings(req, res);
    });


        });


}
```